# Backup Oracle 10g Database from Windows Server 2003 R2 on which command line is disabled

Tags: oracle10g, windows-server-2003, command-prompt, database-backups

I need to backup Oracle 10g Database from Windows Server 2003 R2 where command line is disabled by some virus problem. RMAN and other graphical utilities are also not working. Only possible thing is that I could take OS file backup of the running database (it can't be stopped also). I do have a trace control file of the database. Please provide some solution so that I could restore the database to a new server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a backup using [Oracle DataPump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm) through SQL:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_datpmp.htm

Here are some examples how to use it:

http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_datapump.html
http://jhdba.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/237/